# HTML: Submit star rating into my SQL database

Tags: javascript, php

I currently have a working review form that the user can write a review about a hotel. So far it takes in a title and body but i now wish to implement a star rating so the user selects a rating and it will submit to my database. I currently have the code where the user can submit the title and body, however the star rating does not submit and does not submit to my database. Can anyone advise ?

ReviewController.php

```
    public function store(Request $request)
{
    $this->validate($request, [
        'title' => 'required' ,
        'body' => 'required' ,
        'post_id' => 'required'
    ]);

    $review = new Review;
    $review->title = $request->input('title');
    $review->body = $request->input('body');
    $review->rating = $request->input('rating');
    $review->post_id = $request['post_id'];
    $review->save();
    return redirect('/posts')->with('success', 'post created');
}
```

Show.blade.php

```
    <h1>Reviews</h1>
@if(count($review) > 1)
    @foreach($review as $reviews)
        <div class= "well"> 
            <h3><a href="/reviews/{{$reviews->title}}">{{$reviews->title}} </a>{{$reviews->rating}}</h3><small>{{$reviews->created_at}}</small><br>
            <small>{{$reviews->body}}</small> 
           <br>
           <br>
        </div>

        @endforeach

        @else
    </p>no posts found</p>
    @endif     
@endsection
```

Javascript:

```
var count;
 function starmark(item)
{
  count=item.id[0];
  sessionStorage.starRating = count;
  var subid= item.id.substring(1);
    for(var i=0;i<5;i++)
      {
        if(i<count)
      {
    document.getElementById((i+1)+subid).style.color="orange";
      }
        else
      {
    document.getElementById((i+1)+subid).style.color="black";
    }
        }
            }
```

When i submit this to my database, the values appear as NULL, however i want them to have a value from 1-5.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While `<input>` elements can send data in a form, `<span>` elements cannot. Now you are using a function in JavaScript to simulate this kind of behavior by trying to get the value from the hovered or clicked span. The `sessionStorage.starRating = count` should be `sessionStorage.setItem('starRating', count)` to store the value into the session storage. But that's not the culprit.

Instead of using `<span>` elements, use `<input type="radio">` elements to indicate the rating the user gives. While styling may look difficult, it can be fairly easy by using the `<label>` element as the styling point. When you connect the `<label>` with the `for` attribute to the id of the `<input>` element it belongs to, it becomes clickable. Meaning that whenever I click the label, the input will be clicked as well and will therefor be selected.

So you hide the input and style the label. And in CSS you say how the clicked label is supposed to look based on the currently selected input. The `:checked` psuedo selector is a real lifesaver here.

Putting this all together in your form makes the currently selected radio button to be send to the server with the proper `name` and `value` pair without having to do any JavaScript.

Check out the snippet below to see it work. The JavaScript part can be ignored as it is merely a demonstration.

```js
/**
 * For demonstration purposes.
 * Logs the currently submitted 'rating' value.
 */
const form = document.querySelector('form');
form.addEventListener('submit', event => {
  const formData = new FormData(event.target);
  const rating = formData.get('rating');
  console.log(rating);
  event.preventDefault();
});
```

```css
.star-input {
  display: none;
}

.star {
  color: gold;
}

.star-input:checked + .star ~ .star {
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.13.0/css/all.min.css">
<form>
  <input type="radio" class="star-input" name="rating" id="star-1" value="1">
  <label for="star-1" class="star"><i class="fas fa-star"></i></label>
  <input type="radio" class="star-input" name="rating" id="star-2" value="2">
  <label for="star-2" class="star"><i class="fas fa-star"></i></label>
  <input type="radio" class="star-input" name="rating" id="star-3" value="3">
  <label for="star-3" class="star"><i class="fas fa-star"></i></label>
  <input type="radio" class="star-input" name="rating" id="star-4" value="4">
  <label for="star-4" class="star"><i class="fas fa-star"></i></label>
  <input type="radio" class="star-input" name="rating" id="star-5" value="5" checked>
  <label for="star-5" class="star"><i class="fas fa-star"></i></label>
  <button type="submit">Send</button>
</form>
```

Comment: You are welcome :). If it's a new question then please submit it as a new question. It will help keep this thread clean and maybe helpful for others with the same issue. Otherwise if it's related to the answer I gave or I left something unanswered, then shoot.

Comment: I will do both, all i need to know is now that it is stored in my database, how will i output it as stars. In my database it stores as 3 or 4 or 5 (whatever user inputs), how will i output that as stars. Right now i have the following code in Show.blade.php (updated)

Comment: You can see it outputs {{$reviews ->ratings}} however i need it to output as a star

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61208283/laravel-output-value-as-a-star-rating